# Cholesky decomposition with jeigen?

Tags: java, linear-algebra, eigen

I looked for fast java linear algebra library. I tried many of them(jblas, ujmp, ejml and others). In terms of performance finally I found more reliable the [jeigen](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen) (java wrapper for c++ [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library). But wrapper has no Cholesky decomposition. But original eigen it has. Is there a way to add decomposition to wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a Java wrapper that performs a Cholesky Decomposition. Perhaps another user will post after me who is more knowledgeable specifically about Java and jeigen.

However, I can offer some help on your underlying problem, which is to perform a Cholesky Decomposition; I recently wrote a C++ program that performs a Cholesky Decomposition on a real, symmetric, positive-definite, matrix. The source code is freely available on GitHub:

https://github.com/dcb2015/dpotrf_ak1/blob/master/dpotrf_ak1.cpp

You can:

1) use the complete C++ program as-is in your own C++ compiler, or use the C++ source in your own program, if you know C++.

2) translate the C++ routine into Java for use in your own program. The sub-routine that performs the decomposition is quite small. And Java syntax is very similar to C/C++ syntax, so the translation should not be difficult. (Actually, I usually try to avoid the "++" aspects of the language and code as close to simple "C" as possible.) If writing the Java program is part of your work or assignment, this might be your best option.

3) use a ready-for-use JavaScript version of this program which is available online (see my Profile for the site.) If you do not have to write this program yourself, but only need the results of a decomposition, try it out. It may help you out of a tough spot.